# How to create a window outside the screen

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am studying MAC OS development and I used Swift and Cocoa to create a window that I want to display outside the screen.
My code looks like this：

```
  @IBAction func tapShowSplitWindow(_ sender: Any) {
        let initRect = NSRect(x: -100, y: -100, width: 300.0, height: 300.0)

        var window = NSWindow(contentRect: initRect,styleMask: .titled, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.contentView = NSView()
        window.contentView?.wantsLayer = true
        window.contentView?.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
        
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    }
```

The window will appear in the bottom left corner of the screen, and I expect it to be outside the screen.

so why? and how to show it outside

Comment: I don't know if the system allows this, but I certainly hope it doesn't. I've ran into some bugs where windows shoot far off screen when plugging/unplugging monitors (where they only show in mission control, and it's really hard to get them back), but it's just that, _a bug_. It just doesn't make sense, why would you want this?

Comment: I've been in this situation and it's a bad experience. But the system should not allow developers to do this, because there are many applications that need to do this, for example, I am developing a window management app

Comment: Hmmm interesting. I don't see any mention in the API docs that it would adjust these rects to move them on-screen. Did you try modifying the position *after* creation? There's a bunch of similar functions under the "sizing windows" section, I would try them all. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow

Comment: Now that I think about it, I have seen some UI do this, such as the picture-in-picture video player, and the notes app in the bottom right screen corner. I thought perhaps these "windows" just cut off their size so that they're fully on screen (with the illusion that there's more content extending off screen), but I don't think that's actually the case. I "tucked" the PIP view on a screen edge, and took a window screen shot of it. The result was full size (interestingly, it has the little chevron arrow on both sides :) ).

Comment: Yes. I tried to create the window first and then change the position and that's ok! But it can't detach from the screen at the top, only on the left, right and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

`window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)` moves the window on screen. If you really want the window to be half visible then you can move it back with `setFrameOrigin`

```
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
window.setFrameOrigin(window.frameRect(forContentRect:initRect).origin)
```

Comment: I actually tested it and found it could! But I can't seem to adjust the Y-axis to the top of the screen

Comment: See [Dragging a NSWindow higher than the menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555014/dragging-a-nswindow-higher-than-the-menubar)

Comment: I tried this one, and it can only be dragged to the menu bar, but when you release the mouse, it shows up at the bottom of the menu bar, not on the menu bar

Answer (score 0):

```swift
// Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808924/placing-nswindow-at-top-of-screen-without-1-pixel-margin
class FullscreenWindow: NSWindow {
    override func constrainFrameRect(_ frameRect: NSRect, to screen: NSScreen?) -> NSRect {
        print("Rect: \(frameRect)")
        return NSRect(origin: .zero, size: frameRect.size)
    }
}
```

You can override the `constrainFrameRect` to set the rect of the window.